# Unusual interference

Tags: interference

I'm experiencing an effect somewhat like GSM frame-rate audio break-through in my audio systems - completely different frequencies but equally wideband. I've noticed it occasionally in the past - always at this precise time of year.

The sound is hard to describe but is perhaps something like a tinkling of small bells, a scraping of hooves (perhaps akin to those of [**Rangifer tarandus**](https://www.google.co.nz/search?q=reindeer&biw=1422&bih=998&source=lnms&tbm=isch&sa=X&ved=0ahUKEwjdz6WbgfXJAhWDJKYKHebAARwQ_AUIBigB&dpr=0.9#tbm=isch&q=+Rangifer+tarandus+%2B%22santa+claus%22) ) and perhaps a distant, deep and resonant 'Ho ho ho'?

I'm told that NORAD ([North American Aerospace Defense command](https://wiki2.org/en/North_American_Aerospace_Defense_Command) ) have had possibly related issues and have implemented an official [NORAD tracking system](https://www.noradsanta.org/)  active specifically at this time of year.

Any clues?

Regardless, merry Christmas.

**______________________________**

*One might hope this post would survive a few hours before suffering the inevitable fate.*

Comment: An up-vote. Wow :-). Merry Christmas to whoever it was :-)

Comment: Have another and merry xmas but next time please post a data sheet link.

Comment: I haven't experienced this for nearly a year, so I can't investigate at the moment. Everything happens to us last in California.

Comment: Sure it's not Santa's deer communicate?

Comment: Santa forgot to turn off countermeasures after having to fly over Ukraine.

Comment: I don't know the solution to the problem but pretty sure it involves a flux capacitor.  Merry Christmas and happy holidays to all!

Comment: Without a schematic we can't tell what you're asking.  Also, how are we supposed to know what you think "small" bells are? "Deep" and "resonant" are undefined.  We do engineering here, not handwaving.  Closing this mess (although I'm busy now and probably won't get to it until Saturday).

Comment: This could be due to seasonally induced photonic oscillations.  Often as a result of someone hanging Christmas lights in your proximity. A simple way to solve the issue is to trace the suspect wiring back to the source of the noise then place a tray of home baked cookies and a tall glass of milk close by that location. By morning some or all of the items may be consumed and the noise should be gone.

Comment: @OlinLathrop amazing comment. I can't stop laughing.

Comment: @OlinLathrop Yes. Well done. Now if we can work some Christmas spirit into newbie responses ... :-) | BUT not meaning to ruin your excellent response by snide carping. |Hoping for all of us Peace on list and goodwill to All :-).

Answer (score 5):

It's an experiment [someone](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Santa_Claus) tried a long time ago to teach animals to fly and it got a little out of hand.

[NORAD](http://www.noradsanta.org/) has been tracking the repercussions of this experiment for the past 60 years and as far as they can tell the main side effects have been people breaking out in laughter and cheer.

There was a [brief scare in 1993](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/The_Nightmare_Before_Christmas) when a slightly confused imposter tried the same experiment, but luckily this was quickly remedied.